# laravel hasManyDeepFromRelations with group by

Tags: laravel, eloquent, group-by

Models and relations

```
class Publisher extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships;

    public function collections(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Collection::class)
            ->orderBy('title')
            ->using(CollectionPublisher::class);
    }

    public function series(): HasManyDeep
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->collections(), (new Collection())->series());
    }
}
```

```
class Collection extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships, Translatable;

    public function editions(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Edition::class);
    }

    public function series(): HasManyDeep
    {
        return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->editions(), (new Edition)->series());
    }
}
```

```
class Edition extends Model
{
    use HasRelationships, LoadsRelationshipsWithoutScopes, Translatable;

    public function series(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Series::class);
    }

    public function collection(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Collection::class);
    }
}
```

And of course there is a `Series` model.

---

The problem is that the `series` relation on the `Publisher` is returning each `Series` as many times as there is an `Edition` for that `Publisher` in the `Series`

How do I trim it down so each series is only returned once?

A simple `groupBy('series.id')` does not work due to the full group by limitations, and I'm not sure how to get around this using the has many deep package.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with a solution

On the `Publisher` model:

```
public function series(): Builder
{
    return $this->hasManyDeepFromRelations($this->collections(), (new Collection())->series())
        ->getQuery()
        ->select('series.*')
        ->groupBy('series.id');
}
```

The `getQuery()` part (undocumented in Laravel) limits the scope and allows the `groupBy()` to work

Thanks to Jonas Staudenmeir for the help